# I have to send this rows variable to front end. i cannot code app.get() method inside the app.post method. how to solve this problem please

Tags: node.js, get

how to send this row variable to front-end

```js
app.post('/database/post/itemId', (req, res) => {
  let query = `SELECT * FROM products WHERE itemId='${req.body.itemId}'`;
  db.all(query,[],(err, rows ) => {
      if(err) throw err
      // console.log(**rows**)
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.post('/database/post/itemId', (req, res) => {
  let query = `SELECT * FROM products WHERE itemId='${req.body.itemId}'`;
  db.all(query,[],(err, rows ) => {
      if(err) throw err
      // console.log(**rows**)
      res.send(rows) // <------ try doing this
  }); 
})
```